# Column of Checkboxes Tracking Checked History

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

Have been looking everywhere for any type of solution... Funny because it's a simple problem. Using Google Sheets I would like to be able to track when a check box has been set to "TRUE" without the value decreasing when set to "FALSE". I could easily track when it is set to "TRUE" using =COUNTIF. The problem being, Tracking needs to be 24/7 by multiple users and I'm not always around to input the info manually. ALSO if possible, actual tracking will be on the same sheet but separate tabs. I will copy what I've already failed with.

```
function totalBoxes(e) { 
const totalCell = "N5" 
const checkBoxColumn = 14; 
const checkBoxStartingRow = 5;
 const checkBoxEndRow = 36; 
const range = e.range; 
const col = range.getColumn(); 
const row = range.getRow(); 
if (col == checkBoxColumn && 
(row >= checkBoxStartingRow && 
row <= checkBoxEndRow) && 
e.value === 'TRUE') {
 const totalRange = 
range.getSheet().getRange(totalCell) 
const currentValue = totalRange.getValue(); 
totalRange.setValue(currentValue+1) 
}
}
```

If possible a way to track the total amount of boxes set to TURE- without the number decreasing when set to FALSE.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, I cannot understand the relationship between `I'm not always around to input the info manually.` and your question. Also, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of the **number** of checkboxes on a given sheet that are checked as "true".

The following script appears long (I have included several `Logger` statements to check values at key points), but the essence is simple. It uses `Event Objects` to confirm that sheet name and the checkbox value.

```
function onEdit(e){

  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var editedSheetName = e.source.getSheetName()
  var editedValue = e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet name = "+editedSheetName+", edit value = "+editedValue)

  if (editedSheetName == "Sheet1" && editedValue == "TRUE"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: PASS: Checked box on this sheet")
    var analysisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Analysis")
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(editedSheetName)
    // get the existing value from cell A1
    var totalTrueThis = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
    
    // add 1 to the value
    var newTrue = totalTrueThis +1
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: old value = "+totalTrueThis+", new value = "+newTrue)
    // update values in cell A1 on this sheet and another sheet
    sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(newTrue)
    analysisSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(newTrue)
  }
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: FAIL: Checked box NOT on this sheet")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will track the number of times that checkboxes in Sheet0 are checked.  The data is stored in an object which is saved in PropertiesService under the name of "CheckBoxes"

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX" && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let a1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
    let obj;
    let x = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("CheckBoxes");
    if (x) {
      obj = JSON.parse(x);
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(a1)) {
        e.source.toast("Gate2")
        obj[a1] = 1;
        obj.pA.push(a1);
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("CheckBoxes", JSON.stringify(obj));
      } else {
        e.source.toast("Gate3")
        obj[a1] += 1;
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("CheckBoxes", JSON.stringify(obj));
      }
    } else {
      obj = { pA: [] };
      obj[a1] = 1;
      obj.pA.push(a1);
      e.source.toast("Gate4")
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("CheckBoxes", JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  }
}
```

It needs to be a installable trigger because you need permission to use PropertiesService.  You can see the ScriptProperties in the tools section of the script editors.  You will have to refresh the page everytime you look at it.

Property pA is just an array of object properties in the order that they were created.  I find it handy to have such an array when I wish to loop through all of the properties to display the results.

If you wish you may also use this simple function to see the current state of Checkboxes.

```
function displayCheckboxes() {
  Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("CheckBoxes"))
}
```

After checking A1 through A4 once and then resetting and clicking A1 again the CheckBoxes property contains the following string

```
{"pA":["A1","A2","A3","A4"],"A1":2,"A2":1,"A3":1,"A4":1}
```

This is what my Sheet0 looks like:

[image]